# Is it okay to have the same itemprop and itemscope itemtype on multiple location on the page

Tags: html, schema.org, microdata

Is it okay to set the same itemprop and itemscope on the document or is it bad practice?

The reason I ask is my view layout doesn't display the type in a linear fashion, eg. a company avatar is be on the sidebar and the company name which is the title is on the `article > header` block.

Code example:

```
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Order">
  <div itemprop="seller" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Organization">
    <b itemprop="name">ACME Supplies</b>
  </div>

  <div class="reviews">
     <p>Great company! - Jane</p>
  </div>

  <div itemprop="seller" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Organization">
    <span itemprop="url">http://acme-supplies.com</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

I declared the `itemprop="seller"` and `itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Organization"` twice because of how I need to style the page.

1. Displaying the company name
2. Displaying the company url

Comment: If it is for the same organisation, I think you should wrap it within the same itemscope otherwise you may have that url that isn't attached to the organisation name.  There a some online schema validators that will tell you if it is valid and how it will be displayed.  Google has one that will show you how the schema stuff is used in their search results too

Comment: Note that I changed the `span` to an `a` in my answer. The `url` property expects a URL as value, and in Microdata you can only provide a URL with link elements (`a`, `area`, `link`, `img`, etc.).

Answer (score 2):

This is not ideal. It conveys that the order has two sellers. Consumers could guess/assume that it’s the same seller, but they can’t know for sure.

#### `itemid`

Microdata’s `itemid` attribute allows you to give an item a URI (this URI *identifies* the entity described by this item; it doesn’t necessarily have to lead to a page, but it’s a good practice to provide a page with information about the item). By giving both of your `Organization` items the same URI, you convey that these items are about the same entity.

When doing this, there doesn’t seem to be any need to provide the `seller` property a second time.

```html
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Order">
  <div itemprop="seller" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Organization" itemid="/seller/acme-supplies#this">
    <b itemprop="name">ACME Supplies</b>
  </div>

  <div class="reviews">
     <p>Great company! - Jane</p>
  </div>

  <div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Organization" itemid="/seller/acme-supplies#this">
    <a itemprop="url" href="http://acme-supplies.com/">acme-supplies.com</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

(Note: You could also use an external URI for `itemd`, e.g., `http://acme-supplies.com/`, assuming that this URI identifies the seller, and not something else in addition. Strictly speaking, this URI could also represent the seller’s website, etc. Ideally the seller would itself provide a URI that identifies it, but not many do.)

#### `itemref`

Another solution, if it’s possible for you to move the second `Organization` element out of the `Order` element, is Microdata’s `itemref` attribute.

```html
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Order">
  <div itemprop="seller" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Organization" itemref="seller-acme-supplies-url">
    <b itemprop="name">ACME Supplies</b>
  </div>

  <div class="reviews">
     <p>Great company! - Jane</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div>
    <a itemprop="url" href="http://acme-supplies.com/" id="seller-acme-supplies-url">acme-supplies.com</a>
</div>
```

The `Organization` element adds (via its `itemref` attribute) the property defined in the element with the ID `seller-acme-supplies-url`.

You have to make sure that the element with the `id` is not a child of another `itemscope` (otherwise it would also become the `url` of that item).